# C# Entity Framework - IEntityChangeTracker issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

The exception I am receiving is *An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker*.  My code is structured like so...

My context class looks like this:

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext, IDataContext
    {
        public MyContext (string connectionString) :
            base(connectionString)
        { 
        }

        public DbSet<AssigneeModel> Assignees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AssetAssignmentModel> AssetAssignments { get; set; }
 }

public class AssigneeController : Controller
    {
        protected MyContext db = new MyContext(ConnectionString);

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Import(SomeObjectType file)
        {
           AssigneeModel assignee = new AssigneeModel();
           assignee.FirstName = "Joe";
           assignee.LastName = "Smith";

           // Assignees have assets, and the relationship is established via an AssetAssignmentModel entity

            AssetAssignmentModel assetAssignmentModel = new AssetAssignmentModel
            {
                Asset = someExistingAsset,
                // Assignee = assignee, // Don't establish relationship here, this object will be added to the assignee collection
             }

           assignee.AssetAssignments.Add(assetAssignmentModel); // Manually add object to establish relationship
           db.Assignees.Add(assignee); // Add the assignee object 
           // Exception occurs when adding the object above
        };
}
```

EF Version 4.1

Comment: Does Asset = someExistingAsset come from a different context?

Comment: Yes, it comes from a service call from another method...but I would think the context would be disposed of?

Comment: That's the problem - you need to detach that entity from the other, and then attach it to this new context, or use the same context for all the calls

Comment: I've moved the comment to an answer since I believe this helped you based on the upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from your Asset object, when you're getting it from the other method, you'll need to explicitly detach it from that context, before adding it to this new context.   As Julie mentioned, the entity instance will carry the context with it, but the porblem wasn't with the `AssigneeModel` you created, but with the `someExistingAsset` you retrieved.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, especially since your original comment on the question gave me a quick answer/reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this as EF4.1 (where I expected code first & dbcontext) but it looks like a side effect of EntityObject (edmx, objectcontext, default code gen in VS2008 & VS2010).

In that case, if you have an entity (that derives from EntityObject) and you dispose its' context without first detaching the entity, the entity instance still has an artifact of that context. So when you try to attach it to another context, it gives this message. THat was a problem with EF 3.5 and EF4 if you aren't using POCOs. I haven't had to wrestle with it in a long time but I remember the sting. :)